# Avoid Theme Compilation during module activation in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware, shopware6

We are activating a couple of modules using a series of commands like this:

```
php bin/console plugin:install -a 'Modulenamea'
php bin/console plugin:update 'Modulenamea'
php bin/console plugin:install -a 'Modulenameb'
php bin/console plugin:update 'Modulenameb'
```

this seems to rebuild the theme each time.

We do a final `bin/build-storefront.sh` anyways, so a lot of time is wasted here.

Is there a way to activate the plugins without building the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; you should be able to pass the `--skip-asset-build` option in these commands:

- plugin:install
- plugin:uninstall
- plugin:activate
- plugin:deactivate
- plugin:update

Looking at the code, it looks promising:

```php
if ($input->getOption('skip-asset-build')) {
    $context->addState(PluginLifecycleService::STATE_SKIP_ASSET_BUILDING);
}
```

Then I can track it to the "activate" part of your install command `install -a`:

```php
public function pluginActivate(PluginPreActivateEvent $event): void
{
    if ($this->skipCompile($event->getContext()->getContext())) {
        return;
    }
    ...
    $this->themeLifecycleHandler->handleThemeInstallOrUpdate(
        $storefrontPluginConfig,
        $configurationCollection,
        $event->getContext()->getContext()
    );
...
}
...
private function skipCompile(Context $context): bool
{
   return $context->hasState(Plugin\PluginLifecycleService::STATE_SKIP_ASSET_BUILDING);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! It's available since 6.4.8.0 which was released 9.2.2022 :-)

Comment: alright alright, we will avoid shaming you this time around :P